# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at login after amdgpu install

Tags: graphics, radeon, opencl, amdgpu-pro

I have a new Lenovo laptop with an AMD Radeon RX 500 graphical card. There is also an integrated Intel graphical card. I just installed the latest Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS one week ago.
I would like to install OpenCL sdk. I downloaded the official drivers https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/radeon-500-series/radeon-rx-500-series/radeon-rx-550, installed them as instructed, but after rebooting could not login into Ubuntu. I read all across the internet and this issues is common, but nothing seemed to work for me.

When I tried amdgpu-pro-install --px I got Unable to locate package xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-amdgpu-pro. I later read that this option was deprecated. I also tryed the -headless installation and got the same result.

When I run amdgpu-pro-install I get WARNING: amdgpu dkms failed for running kernel. My kernel is 4.18.0-15-generic.

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot?

Comment: Yes, Secure Boot was disabled

Comment: Maybe the driver is incompatible with the 4.18 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to login after uninstalling `amdgpu`:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> in login screen.
2. Login with your credentials.
3. Run `amdgpu-uninstall`
4. Run `reboot`

Comment: I know how to uninstall it, but this still does not solve my problem. How can I install the amdgpu-pro drivers on Ubuntu with two graphical cards? I would really like to use OpenCL which is impossible without the drivers.

Comment: @JanaF Try to upgrade to Ubuntu 18.10 or better to 19.04. As Pilot6 mentioned in comment it may be incompatibility with kernel.